# SQL Server Geo Clustering

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, sql-server-2008, windows-clustering

I want to have SQL Server Multi Site Clustering. I have experience with single site 2 node cluster but i have a scenario where i have a secondary site. In case of network failure on Site1 My ISP is redirecting my traffic to Site2. So i need to deploy Node1 at Site1 and Node2 at Site2 or Node1 & 2 at Site1 and Node3 at Site2. I really don't have specific read requirements like how Availability Groups describes. My main requirement is HA + Service Availability. So Kindly Suggest what kind of deployment will be best for this case.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 and below, multi-site cluster is not supported natively without having to implement a stretched VLAN.

You can refer [Multi site cluster on windows server 2008 R2](https://clusteringformeremortals.com/2009/09/15/step-by-step-configuring-a-2-node-multi-site-cluster-on-windows-server-2008-r2-%E2%80%93-part-1/)

For SQL 2012 onwards SQL Always On Failoaver Cluster instance is a great feature to use which supports multi-subnet cluster [SQL 2012 AlwaysOn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781257.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Shareef, I will be using SQL 2012 so AlwaysOn FCI will be choice as i already have deployed the same on singe site. For me to test this scenario can you suggest me any opensource storage solution which can perform replication. And i want ask how the Site1 Node(s) will decide they have to fail-over to Site2 in-case of Site1 WAN is down. I think of writing an script in Site1 servers to ping some public sever and in-case that is not reachable, disable the network adapter. Kindly suggest.

Comment: I do not have expertise in Storage solutions, so cannot comment on it. For a multi-site cluster, Microsoft recommends having an even number of nodes and, for the quorum configuration, using the **Node and File Share Majority** option, that is, including a file share witness as part of the configuration. The file share witness can be located at a third site, that is, a different location from the main site and secondary site, so that it is not lost if one of the other two sites has problems. Further reference [https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197575(v=ws.10).aspx]

Comment: What would happen if the third site with file share witness goes down ?

Comment: If you have your Cluster nodes up and running and you loose connectivity to File Share Witness (3rd site) then the cluster would continue to run provided you have enough number of Cluster Nodes up and running. For High Availability, you can configure File Share Witness on separate Cluster.

Comment: Shareef i am still confused about this, suppose i have only Node1 running at Site1 and Node2 inactive at Site2 and assuming that i have File Share Witness at 3rd Site. So what will be my fail-over cases ?